# Error in subset.default(data, Parameter == parm) : object 'Parameter' not found while running example in cenGAM package

Tags: r

I am running the example of `Tobit I` regression using `GAM` model with the `cenGAM` package.
However, running the example provided in the manual of the package gave me the following error:

> Error in subset.default(data, Parameter == parm) : 
>     object 'Parameter' not found

Here is the code I ran:`

```
library(cenGAM)

# Generate random data
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(2*rnorm(300), 100)
yn <- 2*x[,3] + 4*cos(x[,1]*2)
y <- yn + rnorm(100)
ycensored <- pmax(y, 0) # data left-censored at 0
ycensored <- pmin(ycensored, 4) # data right-censored at 4
par(mfrow = c(3,3))
# True model
plot(gam(y ~ s(x[,1]) + s(x[,2]) + s(x[, 3])), ylim=c(-5, 5), main = "True")
# Naive estimation
plot(gam(ycensored ~ s(x[,1]) + s(x[,2]) + s(x[, 3])), ylim=c(-5, 5), main = "Naive")
# Tobit I estimation
m <- gam(ycensored ~ s(x[,1]) + s(x[,2]) + s(x[, 3]), family = tobit1(left.threshold=0))
```

Everything worked fine until I ran the last line of the code to fit the `Tobit 1` GAM model.
Could any one know how to fix it?

I am using `R 3.4.1`

Comment: can not reproduce your error. All works fine.

Comment: Thanks for responsing. Which R package did you work on?
I got the same error while trying to use the sum function, for example:
sum(c(1,2,3)). Then I need to add: base::sum(c(1,2,3)) then it worked. But I really don't know what can I do in this case. Any thoughts?

Comment: I just copied your code ...